# bash alternative command with same arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to run this command:

```
cmd -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

but, if `cmd-better` is available, I prefer to execute it with same arguments:

```
cmd-better -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

Finally, my question is, it is possible to have this in only one line, for example:

```
(cmd-better || cmd) -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

(which means execute `cmd-better` (if available) with those arguments, else execute `cmd` with same arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
"$(command -v cmd-better cmd | head -n 1)" -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

I'd do it ahead of time and store the command you want in a variable

Something like:

```
if ! cmd=$(command -v cmd-better); then
    cmd=$(command -v cmd)
fi

"$cmd" -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```